# NameError: uninitialized constant ActsAsVotableMigration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rake, git-clone, acts-as-votable

I just cloned a github repo (of mine) that I had previously deleted from my computer because I messed up the local repo beyond repair. When I tried to run rake db:migrate, I got:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActsAsVotableMigration
/Users/zach/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/Users/zach/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'

Caused by:
NameError: uninitialized constant ActsAsVotableMigration
/Users/zach/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/Users/zach/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I can't seem to find any example of this online. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Could you show the file name of all your migrations, specially the one that defines ActAsVotableMigration?

Comment: Please include your migration files and the name of those files that you are trying to migrate into your db.